# == with array of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

To make it equivalent with:

```
<% unless @article.type.name == "BLOG" || @article.type.name == "LIVE BLOG" %>
```

why can't I feed an array of values like the following?

```
<% unless @article.type.name == ["BLOG", "LIVE BLOG"] %>
```

Is there a trick for this, or does it not exist?

Comment: I'm somewhat new to Ruby, but to me, you can't feed the array in because then @article.type.name would have to be an array, rather than an individual item.

I believe in the Ruby Koans there is an example which shows how to use an array and string and determine if there is a match inside the array.

Comment: @Jalai: you're totally correct here. I don't know if it's poor wording or twisted expectations on Matthew's part. :)

Comment: Why could you? .....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In rails you can use `in?`

```
unless article.type.name.in?(['blog', 'live blog'])
```

In plain ruby, it's `include?`

```
unless ['blog', 'live blog'].include?(article.type.name)
```

Comment: Thank you Sergio, that's great. I as unaware of that syntax.

Comment: @MatthewBennett: this is not a special syntax. It's just a method that exists. Ruby/rails is full of useful functionality like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`include?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include%3F):

```
<% unless ["BLOG", "LIVE BLOG"].include?(@article.type.name)  %>
```

Comment: Thank you AbM, that's great. I as unaware of that syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Another "trick" might be to use a regular expression:

```
<% unless @article.type.name =~ /^(BLOG|LIVE BLOG)$/ %>
```

Maybe it's sufficient to just check for "blog":

```
<% unless @article.type.name =~ /blog/i %>
```

You can also use `if` and [`!~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-21-7E) instead of `unless` and `=~`:

```
<% if @article.type.name !~ /blog/i %>
```